# Filter Google Earth Engine image collection between today and 10 days ago

Tags: google-earth-engine, filter, date, google-fusion-tables, google-earth-api

I wrote a small script that filters GEE image collection by date that I'm manually change:

```js
var start_date = '2018-11-02'
var end_date = '2018-11-30'


// choose image collection
var ls8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_RT_TOA')
.filterDate(start_date, end_date)
.filterBounds(fc)
.select('B1','B2','B3','B4','B5');
```

fc is a feature collection. This works fine but I'm looking for a way to change the end_date for today and the start_day for 10 (or some other number) days before today, automatically. So every time I ran the script it looks for images in the last 10 days.

Maybe something like:

```js
var start_date = ee.Date(Now-10)
var end_date = ee.Date(Now)
```

Is there something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var newDate = new Date();
var today = ee.Date(newDate);
var previous = today.advance(-10, 'day');

print(newDate); print(today); print(previous);
```